# For infinite loop

Tags: javascript

well i was trying to write a for condition in java script when suddenly it so happened that i started getting the message 3 to 4 times instead of just once i first defined both the variables and then wrote a for code in which i nested and if else statement and then closed all of them but it so happens that there is an infinite loop created.I tried the following:-

```
function setValue(){
    myVariable1= document.forms["myform"]["ram"].value;
    var xuv = ["go", "no", "yes"];

    for (i=0;i<xuv.length;i++)
    {
        if (myVariable1 === xuv[0])
        {       
            alert("yes this game can run")
        }
        else 
        {       
            alert("No, This game cannot run")
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Where did you call `setValue`? Apart from a few missing [`var` declarations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) (`myVariable1`, `i`) it looks good.

Comment: It’s impossible for that to be an infinite loop (unless you’ve overriden `alert` to change a global `i`). Getting a message 3 or 4 times is normal, because you are `alert`ing one message or another 3 times.

Comment: check your btn event handler. you might be subscribing to event multiple times. Also, your loop will always run 3 times with 3 alerts for one setValue call. put break in success condition.

Comment: You are doing one `alert()` call for every item inside the xuv array.

Comment: Btw, why are you using a loop if you don't access `i` anywhere?

Comment: ok thak you @Bergi but could you please fix the code and answer it

Comment: Also, `xuv[0]` should be `xuv[i]`.

Comment: you will always see the message 3 times because your array has the size 3

Comment: hey thank you for all the answers sorry for adding the infinite loop at the question i did that because at first it was showing a 1000 times but i could not fix it but now its showing just 3 to 4 times can someone tell a method for it to show the alert only 1 time.

Answer (score 2):

I think you meant to index the array:

```
if (myVariable1 === xuv[i])
```

Currently you're just checking `xuv[0]` with each iteration of the loop.  So if `xuv[0]` satisfies your condition and the loop iterates a few times, you'll see your message a few times.  If it doesn't, you'll never see it.

If it was an *infinite* loop then you'd never *stop* seeing it...

Answer (score 0):

```
function setValue(){
    myVariable1= document.forms["myform"]["ram"].value;
    var xuv = ["go", "no", "yes"];
    var canRun = false; //i asume the programm can't run

    for (i=0;i<xuv.length;i++)
    {
        if (myVariable1 === xuv[i]) //changed from 0 to i here
        {   
            //but when my input is in the array it can run
            canRun = true;  
        }
    }

    if (canRun)
    {   
        alert("yes this game can run");
    }
    else 
    {       
        alert("No, This game cannot run");
    }
};
```

your problem was, that you checked 3 times if your input is `go`.
What i think you are trying to do is check if your input is in the array.
You also want to print just one alert which i do in the `if-block` after the loop

Comment: thank you @Philipp Sander thank you very much you fixed my code thank you so much and if this app gives a good result i will surely mention you in it thank you sooo much and thank you others who too helped me in this tough situation

Answer (score 0):

Because you are comparing same index in a loop so condition always gets true and its alert, even condition fails it will alert 3 times until you break the loop or it reaches the stop condition:

```
function setValue(){
    var myVariable1= document.forms["myform"]["ram"].value;//add var otherwise it would expect it as global
    var xuv = ["go", "no", "yes"];

    for (var i=0;i<xuv.length;i++)
    {
        if (myVariable1 === xuv[i]) //changed from 0 to i here
        {       
            alert("yes this game can run");
            return;
        }
        else 
        {       
            alert("No, This game cannot run");
            return;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: this will return after 1 iteration

Comment: only one alert will occur as OP wants